# UITabBarController with more than six icons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder, uitabbarcontroller

i'm developing an iPhone application and i'm implementing the navigation among views with the UITabBarController.

The documentation says :

> "The tab bar has limited space for
>   displaying your custom items. If you
>   add six or more custom view
>   controllers to a tab bar controller,
>   the tab bar controller displays only
>   the first four items plus the standard
>   More item on the tab bar. Tapping the
>   More item brings up a standard
>   interface for selecting the remaining
>   items. The interface for the standard
>   More item includes an Edit button that
>   allows the user to reconfigure the tab
>   bar. By default, the user is allowed
>   to rearrange all items on the tab bar.
>   If you do not want the user to modify
>   some items, though, you can remove the
>   appropriate view controllers from the
>   array in the
>   customizableViewControllers property."

Is there a way i can force the control to use exactly six icons without adding the "More ..." one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could subclass the object, and override its drawing properties, but it would most likely be rejected by Apple, as it is an inconsistant UI, and would go against the holy HIGs.

Comment: If Apple rejects apps because of not following the HIG, 90% of all apps wouldn't be in the app store :)

Comment: So can i subclass the object and still have good chances for my app to be approved?

Comment: Well, if you make it identical to a `UITabBar` but with six tabs it *might* be rejected, but if you make it look a lot different then it probably has more chance.

Comment: Facebook managed to fit in 6 icons on the tab bar without rejection

Answer (score 0):

No, the tab bar will only accommodate up to five items. Once you add more than that you get four plus the more button showing.

Comment: I know that, but is there a way, maybe subclassing the object?